# Prove $(n!)/n^n \leq 1/2^{k}$, where $k$ is the floor of $n/2$.

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial, natural-numbers

I suppose the natural way to prove this is by induction. When I follow the rather natural steps $$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n}} \leq \frac{n!}{(n)^{n}}$$ in order to apply the induction hypothesis, however, I obtain for $n+1$ exactly the same bound I assumed for $n$. This is not a problem if $n+1$ is odd, because then the floor of $n/2$ and $(n+1)/2$ coincide, but how can I "detect" the change in the case that $n + 1$ is even?

Comment: Use $(n+1)^n = n^n \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\geq 2$ using binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than proceeding by induction, note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{k!}{n^k} \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (k+1)}{n^{n-k}}
\leq \frac{k!}{n^k}
= \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
\leq \frac{1}{2^k},
\end{align*}
since $k\leq 2n$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$\frac{n!}{n^n} = \left( \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{2}{n} \cdots \frac{n/2}{n} \right) \cdot  \cdots \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{n}{n}  \leq \left( \frac{1}{2} \cdots \frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot 1 \cdots 1 = \frac{1}{2^k}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $(n+1)^n = n^n \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\geq 2$ using binomial theorem.

Answer (score -1):

This is obvious:
$$2^k\cdot n!=2(2\cdot 2)\cdots(2\cdot\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor) \cdot (\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1)\cdots n<n^n.$$

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote?